# SQL Parent-Child structure

Tags: sql, parent-child

I have got a parking application and for its scheduling part I have got the following 2 tables:

Schedule:

- ScheduleId (PK)
- StartDate
- EndDate
- ParentScheduleId (Not sure though if I really needs this!)

ScheduleDetail

- ScheduleDetailId (PK)
- ScheduleId (FK)
- DayOfWeek
- StartTime
- EndTime
- IsActive

Within one Schedule period (eg. StartDate: 1/1/2016 - EndDate: 1/1/2017) I can have one or more Schedule(s) (eg. StartDate: 1/3/2016 - EndDate: 7/3/2016, StartDate: 1/5/2016 - EndDate: 25/5/2016), each with their own ScheduleDetail. And even within each sub schedule I can have one or more Schedule(s).

I basically ended up with this structure to let user define different availability within a certain period. For instance if for the year 2016 they wanted to have different types of availability during the Christmas public holiday or any other occasions. Or if they wanted to remove a certain day(s) from a period.

My question is how to query such table structure to get the most inner defined Schedule and ScheduleDetails as the correct availability.

Sample data

[image: Schedule]

[image: ScheduleDetail]

I need to have a logic to give the following output as per request:

2/03/2016 10:00 - 2/03/2016 14:00   Falls in ScheduleDetailId of 10, which means not available

1/05/2016 10:00 - 1/05/2016 11:00   Falls in ScheduleDetailId of 15, which means available

10/03/2016 10:00 - 10/03/2016 11:00 Falls in ScheduleDetailId of 20, which means not available

2/01/2016 9:00 - 2/01/2016 11:00    Falls in ScheduleDetailId of 6, which means available

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Can u add some records & expected output in your question ?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I don't see the need for a parent-child relation in the scenario you described.